# How to log exception globally without using try catch statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, error-handling, global

I have several try catch statements in my project but I want to log all exceptions without putting it in the catch statement.

is there any way to monitor all exceptions without putting logging logics in the catch statement like codes down below?

```
// codes.
try {
    // doing something.
} catch (e) {
   return "error message"
}

// global.ascx
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Logging Logic goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short no. All the methods to automatically catch errors where you can handle the logging centrally catch unhandled errors. By manually catching and handling/suppressing them you need to manually log as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IExceptionFilter interface to catch all errors. Here is the sample. I have custom logging. So you can customize it.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ProjectName.Helpers
{
    public class ExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(filterContext.Exception.ToString());

            if (filterContext.Exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                Trace.TraceError(filterContext.Exception.InnerException.ToString());
            }

            var st = new StackTrace(filterContext.Exception, true);
            var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
            var lineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

            var log = new LogObj
            {
                DateInserted = DateTime.Now,
                LogType = LogType.Exception,
                Controller = filterContext.RouteData != null ? (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] : "",
                Action = filterContext.RouteData != null ? (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] : "",
                RouteDataId = filterContext.RouteData != null ? (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"] : "",
                Message = filterContext.Exception.ToString(),
                ExceptionMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message,
                InnerExceptionMessage = filterContext.Exception.InnerException != null ? filterContext.Exception.InnerException.ToString() : "",
                InnerExceptionSource = filterContext.Exception.Source,
                InnerExceptionStackTrace = filterContext.Exception.StackTrace,
                ExceptionDetails = "File: " + frame.GetFileName() + " - Line: " + lineNumber
            };

            LogHelper.WriteLog(LogTarget.Exception, log);
        }
    }
}
```

And you need to register this filter on App_Start/FilterConfig.cs.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MailBulletin
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
        }
    }
}
```